# angularjs ng-grid expand/collapse all row when grouped

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I use angularjs ng-grid.
I want to add a button for expand/collapse all rows, when ng-grid group by some field.  How can I do this?

Comment: why dont you want to use css?

Comment: @YagizOzturk if css can do this. I can use css. Can you give me advice? thanks.

Comment: let me know if answer helps out. Select best answer if it is correct so that others may benefit as well.

Comment: @YagizOzturk got it, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouped part of ng-grid will probably have a class `.ngViewport .ng-scope`

This is where you want to add collapse functionality I guess.

Add this div a `ng-show` attribute dynamically

```
$('.ngViewport').attr('ng-show', 'collapsed'); //This is jquery, you can use angular directives for best practice, dont have time :)
```

Assign it to a button. So whenever you click, it will toggle.

```
<a href="#" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click here to <strong>Toggle (show/hide)</strong> Grid</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @YagizOzturk. it works for non-group, also I've made a function for group.